# List of passwords in a JFrame

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a sort of list for passwords for my fourth quarter project for my AP CS class. And I'm not entirely sure how to do this so it fits. I also want it to be scrollable.

http://postimg.org/image/7rkdy45bz/ - Horrible concept art.

The big box (inside the JFrame) will hold the: [platform] | [username] | [pass] . But I'm not sure how to really do that?

I hope I wasn't too confusing.

NOTE: We have the files and everything else needed, we're just not sure how to actually display the information.

Comment: So if you are referring to those `platform/user/pass` as columns you can use a `JTable` inside of a `JScrollPane`

Comment: You probably won't (or at least you shouldn't) get a very good grade if your app stores or displays the actual password for a user, or uses a file that has the actual passwords in it.

Comment: @FredK all files are encrypted, it's more to show we can do it than to be an actual program. He wants to see what we can do, it doesn't have to be an actual program that'd we say, sell.